# Hibernate: Provider com.bea.xml.stream.EventFactory not found

Tags: hibernate, osgi

I'm in the process of getting Hibernate to work with OSGi, so the base for this project is `org.hibernate.osgi`.

I've created a *persistence.xml* and tried to access it with the following code:

```
BundleContext context = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(getClass()).getBundleContext();
ServiceReference serviceReference = context.getServiceReference(PersistenceProvider.class.getName());
PersistenceProvider persistenceProvider = (PersistenceProvider) context.getService(serviceReference);
EntityManagerFactory emf = persistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory("DemoUnit", null);
```

For some reason, when creating the `EntityManagerFactory`, there is the following exception:

```
javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider com.bea.xml.stream.EventFactory not found
at javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:72)
at javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:178)
at javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:92)
at javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory.newInstance(XMLEventFactory.java:30)
at org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.MappingBinder.<init>(MappingBinder.java:40)
at org.hibernate.boot.spi.XmlMappingBinderAccess.<init>(XmlMappingBinderAccess.java:43)
at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.<init>(MetadataSources.java:87)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:208)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:177)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.Bootstrap.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(Bootstrap.java:83)
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:186)
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:126)
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:81)
at org.hibernate.osgi.OsgiPersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(OsgiPersistenceProvider.java:77)
at org.acme.project.MyTest.getFactory(MyTest.java:28)
```

I assume this to be a bug, since I can't find the package `com.bea.xml.stream` in any P2 repository nor Maven central.

But how do I get Hibernate to take any other XML provider?

(Or whatever `com.bea.xml.stream` might be. At least the code is trying to cast this 'EventFactory ' to 'XMLEventFactory'.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's nothing anybody could have ever found. The bundle that breaks Hibernate is `com.springsource.javax.xml.stream`. I replaced it with `javax.xml.stream` and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the javax/xml folder from local maven repository and try building the project again.
This will solve the problem in some cases.